# How can i update my codes from 5.3 to 7.2 php code

Tags: php

I need to update all my php codes for ** 7.2 ** but i do not know all changelog for php codes,
I was wondering if there is a program to check that are outdated and which are needed to be updated,

i'm thinking something you say you should update Example says: this line of code is old 5.2
because it is removed or changed

My php file folders are up to 50 .php files

I think there should be a program to help you update your codes

Comment: what is this really related to? you posted no code and what the real reason is behind all this. Is this database related by any chance?

Comment: Why not just run your code on 7.2 and see if you get any warnings and/or errors?

Comment: Use a Static language analyzer tool. For eg, this is from the PHP inventor:  https://github.com/phan/phan

More details can be seen at: https://www.exakat.io/php-7-static-analysis-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Use a dummy database and just run it.
If you want to speficly want to check want to see what changed look at this http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php 
This is what changed from 5.6 to 7.0.x and you can also look up what has changed between 5.2 to 5.6.